# SQL Server : list databases available for login

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given SQL Server with different logins mapped to different sets of databases, is there any simple way to list databases available with provided login or given connection string?

Something to be used like that:

```cs
var cstring = "Server=SQLSRV;Trusted_Connection=true;";
var databases = ListAvailableDatabases(cstring);

foreach(var db in databases)
    Console.WriteLine(db);
```

`EXEC sp_databases` doesn't work as user logins have no enough permissions, and `select * from sys.databases where owner_sid=...` doesn't work because users are not owners of databases assigned to them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the stored procedure sp_msloginmappings

```
create table #map(  
 Login  nvarchar(128) NULL,  
 DatabaseName     nvarchar(128) NULL,  
 User   nvarchar(128) NULL,  
 Alias  nvarchar(128) NULL 
)  

insert into #map
EXEC master..sp_msloginmappings

select * from #map

drop table #map
```